# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is my code not working and what does this error mean?

```
import random
initial_val = str(10)
attr_c1_stre = ("Character 1's Strength: ",str(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4)     + initial_val))
attr_c1_skill = ("Character 1's Skill: ",str(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) +     initial_val))
attr_c2_stre = ("Character 2's Strength: ",str(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4)     + initial_val))
attr_c2_skill = ("Character 2's Skill: ",str(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) +     initial_val))
print("attr_c1_stre", "\nattr_c1_skil", "\n\nattr_c2_stre","\nattr_c2_skill")
file = open("Attribute.txt", "w")
file.write(attributes)
file.close()
input("\n\nPress enter to exit")
```

This is what IDLE says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python task - dice\Task 2\python codefor task 2].py", line 3, in <module>
    attr_c1_stre = ("Character 1's Strength: ",str(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Many thanks

Comment: It means what it says; `random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4)` is a floating point number, and `initial_val` is a string. You can't add a number and a string.

Comment: If `a=3.5` and `b="10"`, should `a+b` result in `13.5` or `'3.510'`? Python has no way of knowing which argument should be converted, so it raises an error to let you know you need to be more explicit about the intended result.

Answer (score 6):

`initial_val` is a string:

```
initial_val = str(10)
```

You are trying to add it to a floating point value:

```
random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val
```

`initial_val` should not be a string; leave it as an integer instead:

```
initial_val = 10
```