# Currency convertor using two functions

Tags: python, typeerror, currency

I am trying to make a currency convertor using two functions in one program but for some reason my program either gets this error:

```
line 23, in Input1
    print(amount+"Won equals to "+totalamount+" USD")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Or does not print anything after putting the 'Option' and 'Amount'. This is my program:

```
print("Please choose which currency you want to convert:")
print("A - Korean Won to US Dollar (Exchange Rate: 0.000905)")
print("B - Korean Won to Euro (Exchange Rate: 0.000807350908)")
print("C - Korean Won to Japanese Yen (Exchange Rate: 0.0919061643)")
print("D - Korean Won to Chinese RMB (Exchange Rate: 0.00603703605)")
print("E - Quit")

usd = 0.000905
eur = 0.000807350908
yen = 0.0919061643
rmb = 0.00603703605

def main():
    option =input("Enter your option: ")
    if option== "E":
        exit()
    amount =float(input("Enter the amoutn in Korean Won: "))
    Input1(option, amount)

def Input1(option,amount):
    if option == "A":
        totalamount = (amount * usd)
        print(amount+"Won equals to "+totalamount+" USD")
    elif option== "B":
        totalamount = (amount * eur)
        print (amount+"Won equals to "+totalamount+" Euro")
    elif option== "C":
        totalamount = (amount * yen)
        print (amount+"Won equals to "+totalamount+" Yen")
    elif option== "D":
        totalamount = (amount * rmb)
        print (amount+"Won equals to "+totalamount+" Chinese RMB")
    else:
            print("You entered an invalid input.")
    return option,amount

main()
```

Can you guys give me tips to fix my program? I am still learning python and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @papara, in general, the StackOverflow community will appreciate it if you could cut out unnecessary code and only present a minimal reproducible example of the problem. In your case, for example, such a minimal example could be 


`print(123+"Won equals to "+456+" USD")`

That demonstrates the same error and we can help you faster.

Comment: Also you should google the error message before posting here. If you search for `python unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` you get a lot of results from Stackoverflow that answer this same question, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480060/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-float or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664491/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-str or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106154/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-float

Answer (score 3):

You just need to typecast amount and totalamount variable that is currently float into string

```
print(str(amount)+"Won equals to "+str(totalamount)+" USD")
```

Or use you use format function

```
print("{} Won equals to {} USD ".format(amount, totalamount))
```

And i think format function is better option

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `amount` and `totalamount` to a string before using it in `print()` as string with +. You could use the `str()` method.

```
print(str(amount)+"Won equals to "+str(totalamount)+" USD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an f-string instead of string concatenation; it'll handle the conversion for you!

```
print(f"{amount} won equals to {totalamount} USD")
```

If you did want to do the conversion yourself, it'd look like this:

```
print(str(amount) + "Won equals to " + str(totalamount) + " USD")
```

(edit) to answer the question asked in comments, change your `main()` function to:

```
def main():
    while True:
        option = input("Enter your option: ")
        if option== "E":
            break
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount in Korean Won: "))
        Input1(option, amount)
```

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed my problem. Just one more question.. How can I make it so the program can restart itself again after printing out the conversion result?